# Filter HTML Table Data using Check Boxes?

Tags: html

I am getting Table from a database where I will show the mature records only if a Mature Check Box is checked, so the real thing is that I want to populate data. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need something in your database to identify "Mature Records". Then you just need to modify your query (with something like `AND mature=0`) if the name/value of the checkbox doesn't appear in the submitted form data.

Comment: Yea it is there but real problem is that i am rendering it in table but if i am going to lets suppose change the visibility of the mature row hidden it leave a space of that row which is really messy i want to draw a table at least not that such things but render data (without the tr space) when check box is checked...

Comment: How is that a problem? If you do what I say then there won't be any mature rows in the (HTML) table. If there aren't any, then they won't be taking up space while invisible. (And if you did have them in the data (because you weren't following my advice) then you could set them to display: none instead of the display but invisibly).